# How to convert JSON Web Key Set (JWKS) public keys to PEM file using BASH?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, openssl, jwt, pem

Let's say you use AWS and you want to use ID based authentication using Cognito.

Then `aws` provides you with a public key you can verify the cognito payload with.

Let's also assume you don't want or cannot use any fancy libraries like jose since you are locked in a highly constrained environment.

The way to go is a BASH script that would make good old *Brian Kernighan*
proud.
You have to understand the encoding first.
`Base64Url` needs to be translated to Base64.

This is achieved using padding characters `=`
If the number of characters is divisible by `4` you don't need padding.
This relates to the binary digit representation.
Once that is taken care of you can translate `Base64` to `binary`.

But how do I convert a `JWKS/JWT` to a `PEM` file this using BASH and BASH-programs only?

Comment: You can just ignore `base64 -d` screaming for missing `=` padding like this: `<<<'SGVsbG8geW91Cg' base64 -d 2>/dev/null ||:`

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I came up with following the officual documentation and sources listed below.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decode-verify-cognito-json-token/

Please adapt input url or use json token directly and make sure you have `jq` installed.

Descriptive help is given in the function as comments.

**Tested successfully** on Ubuntu 18.04 and AmazonLinux2 (CentOS) as of 2020-04-28

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# FUNCTIONS
decodeBase64UrlUInt() { #input:base64UrlUnsignedInteger
    local binaryDigits paddedStr
    case $(( ${#1} % 4 )) in
        2) paddedStr="$1=="   ;;
        3) paddedStr="$1="    ;;
        *) paddedStr="$1"     ;;
    esac
    binaryDigits=$(             \
        echo -n "$paddedStr"    \
        | tr '_-' '/+'          \
        | openssl enc -d -a -A  \
        | xxd -b -g 0           \
        | cut -d ' ' -f 2       \
        | paste -s -d ''        \
    )
    echo "ibase=2; obase=A; $binaryDigits" | bc
    # openssl   enc:encoding; -d=decrypt; -a=-base64; -A=singleLineBuffer
    # xxd       "make-hexdump": -b=bits; -g=groupsize
    # cut       -d=delimiter; -f=field
    # paste     -s=serial|singleFile; -d=delimiter
}

base64UrlToHex() { #input:base64UrlString
    local hexStr paddedStr
    case $(( ${#1} % 4 )) in
        2) paddedStr="$1=="   ;;
        3) paddedStr="$1="    ;;
        *) paddedStr="$1"     ;;
    esac
    hexStr=$(                   \
        echo -n "$paddedStr"    \
        | tr '_-' '/+'          \
        | base64 -d             \
        | xxd -p -u             \
        | tr -d '\n'            \
    )
    echo "$hexStr"
    # base64    -d=decode
    # xxd       -p=-plain=continuousHexDump; -u=upperCase
    # tr        -d=delete
}

asn1Conf() { #input:hexStrPlainUpperCase
    local e="$1"
    local n="$2"
    echo "
        asn1 = SEQUENCE:pubkeyinfo
        [pubkeyinfo]
        algorithm = SEQUENCE:rsa_alg
        pubkey = BITWRAP,SEQUENCE:rsapubkey
        [rsa_alg]
        algorithm = OID:rsaEncryption
        parameter = NULL
        [rsapubkey]
        n = INTEGER:0x$n
        e = INTEGER:0x$e
    " | sed '/^$/d ; s/^ *//g'              \
    | openssl asn1parse                     \
        -genconf    /dev/stdin              \
        -out        /dev/stdout             \
    | openssl rsa                           \
        -pubin                              \
            -inform     DER                 \
            -outform    PEM                 \
            -in         /dev/stdin          \
            -out        /dev/
    # sed       /^$/d=removeEmptyLines; /^ */=removeLeadingSpaces
}

main() {
    local e n hexArr
    local jwksUrl="$1"
    local jwkJson=$(curl -sSSL $jwksUrl)
    local kidList=$(jq -r '.keys[].kid' <<< "$jwkJson")
    for keyId in $kidList; do
        n=$(jq -r ".keys[] | select(.kid == \"$keyId\") | .n" <<< "$jwkJson")
        e=$(jq -r ".keys[] | select(.kid == \"$keyId\") | .e" <<< "$jwkJson")
        echo -e "\n$keyId"
        # decodeBase64UrlUInt "$e"
        # decodeBase64UrlUInt "$n"
        asn1Conf $(base64UrlToHex "$e") $(base64UrlToHex "$n")
    done
}

# MAIN
main 'https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json'
exit 0
```

Special thanks to:

Yury Oparin
https://www.yuryoparin.com/2014/05/base64url-in-bash.html

Cédric Deltheil
https://github.com/Moodstocks/moodstocks-api-clients/blob/master/bash/base64url.sh

Alvis Tang
https://gist.github.com/alvis/89007e96f7958f2686036d4276d28e47

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

Either ignore `base64 -d` complaining of truncated input:

```sh
<<<'SGVsbG8geW91Cg' base64 -d 2>/dev/null ||:
```

Or fix the base64 padding with Bash before decoding:

```sh
base64URL='SGVsbG8geW91Cg'

printf -v pad_space '%*s' $((${#base64URL}%4)) ''

padded_base64="$base64URL${pad_space// /=}"

<<<"$padded_base64" base64 -d
```

Comment: What about the URL and the PEM file?